# How to check if an item in an array is a letter?

Tags: javascript

so there's this exercise on coderbyte that goes:

> Have the function SimpleSymbols(str) take the str parameter being
>   passed and determine if it is an acceptable sequence by either
>   returning the string true or false. The str parameter will be composed
>   of + and = symbols with several characters between them (ie.
>   ++d+===+c++==a) and for the string to be true each letter must be surrounded by a + symbol. So the string to the left would be false.
>   The string will not be empty and will have at least one letter.

sample test cases:

> Input:"+d+=3=+s+"
>
> Output:true
>
> Input:"f++d+"
>
> Output:false

and here is the solution that i came up with, but it's not working:

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) { 

  // code goes here 

  var splitted = str.split('')
  var result = splitted.map(function (arr){
      for (var i=0; i<splitted.length; i++){
          if (splitted[i] == '+' && splitted[i+2] == '+' && splitted[i+1] == /[a-z]/gi || && splitted[i+1] == /[A-Z]/gi){
              return true
          }
          return false
      }
      }
  })

 return result;

}

// keep this function call here 
SimpleSymbols(readline());
```

i believe the problem lies within how I wrote the regex condition on the if statement.

so how is the right way to found out that splitted[i+1] is a letter?

Comment: That is not how you use reg exps. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) { 

  // code goes here

  var splitted = str.split('')
  var result = splitted.map(function (arr){
      for (var i=0; i<splitted.length; i++){
          if (splitted[i] == '+' && splitted[i+2] == '+' && 
          (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(splitted[i+1])))
          {
console.log('true');              
return true;
          }else{
          console.log('false');
          return false;
      }
      }
  })

 return result;

}

SimpleSymbols('+d+=3=+s+');
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```js
function SimpleSymbols(str) { 

  // code goes here 

  var splitted = str.split('+')
  var result = splitted.map(function (arr){
      for (var i=0; i < splitted.length; i++){
           if ( /[a-z]/gi.test(splitted[i]) &&  /[A-Z]/gi.test(splitted[i+1])
           ){
              return true
          }
          return false
      
      }
  })

 return result;

}

// keep this function call here 
console.log(SimpleSymbols('f+g+j'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're for loop on splittedArray inside map doesn't make sense, you can directly use index parameter of map

```
`.map(currentValue, index, array)`
```

And also you're not using regex to test string, you're comparing string with regex,

```
`splitted[i+1] == /[a-z]/gi`
```

if you want to use regex you can use this pattern

```
(?:^|[^+])[a-z]|[a-z](?:[^+]|$)
```

[image]

```js
let inputs = ["+d+=3=+s+","f++d+"]

let check = (str) => +(str.match(/(?:^|[^+])[a-z]|[a-z](?:[^+]|$)/gi) || []).length > 0

inputs.forEach(str=> console.log(check(str)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may search for a charecter surrounded by something different than the plus symbol and return false when you find it. Something like this:

```
function isValid(str) {
  return !str.match(/\+[a-z]([^+]|$)|([^+]|^)[a-z]([^+]|$)|([^+]|^)[a-z]\+/gi);
}

isValid("+d+=3=+s+"); /// --> true
isValid("f++d+"); /// --> false
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the simplest solution. Just walk the string and check if each found letter is surrounded by `+` on both sides.

```js
function isEachLetterSurroundedByPlus(str) {
    const re = /[a-z]/i;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (re.test(str[i])) {
            if (str[i - 1] !== "+" || str[i + 1] !== "+")
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(isEachLetterSurroundedByPlus("+s+f+=+d+d=d+"));
console.log(isEachLetterSurroundedByPlus("+s+f+=+d+d+=+d+"))
```